# Check for date range with bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to make a script that is working from 12/24/2020 through 06/01/2021. For now I olny have it working only for 2 dates with this:

```
if [ "$(date +'%m%d')" != "1224" ] && [ "$(date +'%m%d')" != "1226" ];
```

So this script should be working from 12/24 - 01/06.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If you have your `date` command output year, month, day, i.e., 20201224, then you can just use normal string compare for a range check.

Comment: A complication occurs to me: do you want the test to be applied in the local time zone, or GMT, or something else?

Comment: To my local time zone, yes. I'm in Italy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `+%s` option in `date` to convert the start/finish dates to [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You supply the dates using the `-d` option.

Then, you retrieve the current date using `+%s` again and compare using standard integer comparison, like this:

```
start=$(date +%s -d '12/24/2020')
finish=$(date +%s -d '06/02/2021')

now=$(date +%s)
if [ $now -ge $start ] && [ $now -lt $finish ]
then
    echo "Do something"
else
    echo "Skip"
fi
```

**Edit:** For the finish date, its necessary to use the day *after* your intended finishing date and compare using `-lt`. This is because `date` will return the timestamp for the start of the specified date. So doing this, you end up having the comparison succeed until midnight on 06/01/2021. Thanks to @gordon-davisson for pointing this out.

Comment: Small problem: `date +%s -d '06/01/2021'` gets the time midnight at *the beginning of* 06/01/2021. If you want it to work *through* 6/1/2021 (i.e. until the midnight at *the end of* 6/1/2021, you should use  `date +%s -d '06/02/2021'` and a `-lt` test.

Comment: `&&` and multiple tests is preferred over using the deprecated `-a`, see for example [BashFAQ/031](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031#np2).

Comment: That's really unfortunate. I never knew that about `test` (or maybe I did and forgot over time..), and yet it was in the man page all this time: *NOTE: Binary -a and -o are inherently ambiguous. Use 'test EXPR1 && test EXPR2' or 'test EXPR1 || test EXPR2' instead.*

Comment: Is `06/01/2021` January 6 or June 1? I would suggest specifying the dates in ISO format, which `date` understands, and not use the ambiguous US format. So `2021-06-01` for June 1.

Comment: I was just using the original dates verbatim from the question.. But based on that I think the intention was for June 1, which you can tell from the start date 12/24.

Answer (score 0):

```
beg='20201224'
end='20210601'
now=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
if (( beg <= now )) && (( now <= end)); then
```