# Check whether date is within N days of a target in bash

Tags: bash, ssl, awk

Currently this script looks at a cert on an endpoint and let's you know how many days are left until it expires. How can I make this script check a cert on the local server instead of hitting an endpoint as it does now?:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Print the number of days till certificate expiration
#
# Example:
#   $ check_cert.sh sleeplessbeastie.eu
#   81
#   $ check_cert.sh lwn.net
#   630
#
# Exit codes:
#   0   - certificate is not expired
#   1   - certificate is expired
#   254 - certificate is empty
#   255 - DNS resolution failed
#

# temporary file to store certificate
certificate_file=$(mktemp)

# delete temporary file on exit
trap "unlink $certificate_file" EXIT

if [ "$#" -eq "1" ]; then
  website="$1"
  host "$website" >&-
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo -n | openssl s_client -servername "$website" -connect "$website":443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > "$certificate_file"
    certificate_size=$(stat -c "%s" "$certificate_file")
    if [ "$certificate_size" -gt "1" ]; then
      date=$(openssl x509 -in "$certificate_file" -enddate -noout | sed "s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/")
      date_s=$(date -d "${date}" +%s)
      now_s=$(date -d now +%s)
      date_diff=$(( (date_s - now_s) / 86400 ))
      echo "$date_diff"
      if [ "$date_s" -gt "$now_s" ]; then
        exit 0 # ok
      else
        exit 1 # not ok
      fi
    else
      exit 254
    fi
  else
    exit 255
  fi
fi
```

My desired script would allow you to do something like this:

```
check_cert.sh fqdn.cert.name.cer
81
```

Comment: The easy form is to convert your date into a format where ASCII sort order is the same as type-aware sort order. Use YYYY-MM-DD, then you can make your cutoff date _also_ be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, and then it's just a normal string comparison.

Comment: BTW, note that a good [mre] is the **shortest possible code** that produces a given problem. If you just want to compare two dates, there's no reason for a whole bunch of openssl commands in your example; we don't need to know where the dates come from, just what format they're in.

Comment: (There are other approaches, such as epoch time and integer comparison, suggested in [check for date range with bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453087/check-for-date-range-with-bash-scripting))

Comment: Hi @Charles Duffy, I agree with your suggestion about posting only the last bit about the date and not that whole script above it. I'll shorten it down. I was just trying to show the reader that my current method for testing the date on a cert is by analyzing the cert on the endpoint and not on the server itself. But in answer to your other suggestion, the date that is retuned from the "keytool" command is in a different format. Is there a way to convert it from that format to a different one? I don't know if the date command actually recognizes the string "Jan 09 2024" as an actual date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is pretty good at this.

```
python3 -c "
import datetime
import sys
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
key_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%b %d %Y')
difference = key_time - current_time
sys.exit(0 if difference.days < 14 else 1)
" "$( keytool -printcert -file e2.***.*********.com.cer | sed '4q;d' | awk '{print $11,$12,$15}' )"
```

Then you can send your email if the exit code from python is 0.

Comment: My server doesn't have Python3, so I changed this to "python -c", but the script didn't output anything when I checked a cert who's expiration date it Tue Jan 09 15:59:59 PST 2024.

Comment: It doesn't print anything, it just sets an exit code. If you want it to print you could change the `sys.exit` part to `print(difference.days)`, or print and then exit, or however you want to provide feedback to the caller. It does also assume the input date is in the `Jan 09 2024` format that you originally provided, if that format changes you'd have to update the `strptime` call.

Comment: Cool, now it works, you get the credit. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @tjm3772, if the exit code is zero in the "python -c" block of code, and then I do something like `if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then send_mail; else echo "Cert is still current" >&2; fi`, will Bash see the exit code from Python? Or maybe I should just send the mail from inside "python -c". That may be the way to go.

Comment: Bash will see python's exit code that way. You can also send the mail from python if you prefer. The slightly more idiomatic solution in bash is to do `if ! python -c ... ; then send_mail ; else echo "Cert is still current." ; fi` since you just care about success vs failure and not the precise exit code.

Comment: Hi @tjm3772, I got everything working now, if cert < 14 days from expiry, archive, gencert, mail. But the thought now occurs, if this script runs at midnight everyday, what's to prevent it from sending a subsequent cert request. I have to test the modified date of the .csr file, and if it's been modified within 14 days of expiring, don't generate new cert request. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 0):

GNU `AWK` has [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) which you might find helpful for this task.
`mktime` allows you to convert string in `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"` format to time of seconds since start of epoch, `systime` function to get number of seconds since start of epoch now, so in your case you need to

- convert your format into `mktime`-compliant, `Jan 09 2024` should be turned into `2024 01 09 00 00 00`
- use `mktime` function to get number of seconds
- subtract from above value number of seconds since epoch currently i.e. value returned by `systime()`
- if value is lesser or equal 1209600 then alert user about near expiration

1209600 is 14 days in seconds (14*86400).